# What is the name of this classic serif typeface with large round counters?

Tags: font-identification, serif

[image: Photo of wedding stationery]

Can someone help me to find the name of the font in the picture? I’m looking specifically for the capital letters.

[image: Close-up of order of service]

I've tried all of the websites below but came out with nothing:

- WhatTheFont!
- Identifont
- Serif Font Identification Guide
- What Font is

I found this font used for wedding stationery on a picture on Pinterest.

Comment: Thank you so much! I definitely will come back, such great and fast help!

Comment: If an answer solved your question, please consider marking it the 'correct' answer by clicking the checkmark icon next to it. This is great for site stats and helps the answerer's rep (not that I need that last one ;) )

Answer (score 11):

Using just the 'Top table' part of the image and skewing it a bit, [WhatTheFont!](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) gave either [University Roman](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/university/roman-medium/) or [Celtic MN](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itfmecanorma/celtic/regular/) as matches.

### University Roman

[image]

### Celtic MN

[image]

Comment: And as to what the difference between the two is... Beats me.

Comment: There is no difference—Celtic MN (MN = Mecanorma) is simply a relicensed version of Letraset’s University Roman for their [Mecanorma Collections](http://www.myfonts.com/foundry/Mecanorma_Collection). This one, being about as un-Celtic as you could imagine, happens to be singularly poorly named, but that’s neither here nor there.